# Excel VBA: After Filtering column, to replace filtered cells value dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

Like to input into Excel VBA:

Have a Column (V), after filtered for "#N/A"
To replace with formula (=ColC -Col V)
And FillDown rest of Filtered cells in ColV

Have a Column (D), after filtered for "TBA"
To paste into Columns beside (ColE,F,G,H)
And FillDown rest of Filtered cells

Have a Column (J), after filtered for "Blank"
To replace with "TBA"
And FillDown rest of filtered cells in ColJ

For MS Windows Excel 2016

```
    'Record Macro'

'First Case
ActiveSheet.Range("$AA$1:$AA$65303").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]+RC[-1]"
    Range("AA365").Select
    Range("AA365").Select
    Selection.FillDown

'Second Case
Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$L$1:$L$65303").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="TBA"
    Range("L488").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "TBA"
    Range("L479:L488").Select
    Selection.FillRight
    Range("O65307").Select
```

Thank You
Feel free if need clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can use Replace or SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), don't really understand everything You want, but i think these hints are everything You need to do this code :)

```
lLastR = .cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
.Range("J2:J" & lLastR).Replace "", "TBA"
.Range("F2:F" & lLastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) = 1
```